# Is it possible to save a file with an icon using SaveAsDialogBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to save a file after specifying its icon using a save as dialog box in C#.net?

I'm saving an exe file with SaveAsDialogBox() in a folder but failed to assign that exe file an Icon.

**Is there any way to assign that file an icon before or after saving that file?**

```
int num1, num2, num3;

if (Operators.CompareString(this.exePath.Text, "", false) == 0)
{
    num1 = (int)Interaction.MsgBox((object)"Select/browse an exe file to bind...!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, (object)null);
}
else if (Operators.CompareString(this.docPath.Text, "", false) == 0)
{
    num2 = (int)Interaction.MsgBox((object)"Select/browse a docment file (pdf/jpg/doc etc.)...!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, (object)null);
}
else if (Operators.CompareString(this.saveAs.Text, "", false) == 0)
{
    num3 = (int)Interaction.MsgBox((object)"Browse the path to save the output file...!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, (object)null);
}
else
{
    byte[] stub = Resources.stub;
    FileStream fileStream = File.Create(Application.StartupPath + "\\Hello.exe");
    fileStream.Write(stub, 0, stub.Length);
    fileStream.Close();
    FileSystem.FileOpen(1, this.exePath.Text, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Default, -1);
    string str1 = Strings.Space(checked((int)FileSystem.LOF(1)));
    FileSystem.FileGet(1, ref str1, -1L, false);
    FileSystem.FileClose(1);
    FileSystem.FileOpen(2, this.docPath.Text, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Default, -1);
    string str2 = Strings.Space(checked((int)FileSystem.LOF(2)));
    FileSystem.FileGet(2, ref str2, -1L, false);
    FileSystem.FileClose(2);
    FileSystem.FileOpen(3, Application.StartupPath + "\\Stub.exe", OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Default, -1);
    string str3 = Strings.Space(checked((int)FileSystem.LOF(3)));
    FileSystem.FileGet(3, ref str3, -1L, false);
    FileSystem.FileClose(3);
    FileSystem.FileOpen(3, this.saveAs.Text, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.Default, -1);
    FileSystem.FilePut(3, str3 + "@@72389@@" + str1 + "@@72389@@" + str2 + "@@72389@@" + this.n1 + "@@72389@@" + this.n2, -1L, 0 != 0);
    FileSystem.FileClose(3);
    File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "\\Hello.exe");
    Interaction.MsgBox((object)"Files have been binded successfully and stored in defined location", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, (object)null);
    showControls();
}
```

Help will be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without a little more context about what you are doing. Can you please show some code of what you have so far? What's this `.exe` file you are saving, where does it come from? In Windows, the icon for an `.exe` file is embedded in itself.

Comment: @LeandroTase
I'm binding two files using above code I added in the question.

Comment: see this address:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e23a82c-8bed-4b96-8b9a-4c2b6136a622/changing-the-icon-of-exe-files-programatically?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @Xorraxx: I just ended up drooling over my keyboard trying to understand that code. I don't know what you mean by ***binding two files***, do you mean merging? Looks like you have an `.exe` file embedded as a resource in your application (`byte[] stub = Resources.stub;`). That stream of bytes should be in [`PE Format`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). That's the direction you should follow.

Comment: @LeandroTaset:
yes its merging sorry for mistakenly used word bind.

Comment: @Xorraxx .. If i understood it right, then you are trying to save a .exe file and you want to assign particular icon to this file. I feel that .exe belongs to your desktop application and by double clicking it will run in your program, right? If yes then you may choose a different nice approach to do this.

Comment: @AmneshGoel...
you are right, but what else nice approach is?

Comment: I have posted full answer for you. Check it out.

Answer (score 4):

I have successfully changed the icon with the code below,
after all this I got a bug, that the exe I used to be experimented is not working anymore.

**Whats wrong with this code which made the exe useless?**

```
IntPtr hUpdate1 = IconClass.NativeMethods.BeginUpdateResource(exeFileName, false );
```

Is it due to the resource update in the above line of code.

```
 IconClass.IconFile iconFile = IconClass.IconFile.FromFile(iconFileName);
  IntPtr hUpdate1 = IconClass.NativeMethods.BeginUpdateResource(exeFileName, false );
  byte[] iconGroupData = iconFile.CreateIconGroupData(iconBaseID);
  IntPtr hUpdate2 = hUpdate1;
  IntPtr num1 = new IntPtr(14L);
  IntPtr type1 = num1;
  IntPtr num2 = new IntPtr((long) iconGroupID);
  IntPtr name1 = num2;
  int num3 = 0;
  byte[] data1 = iconGroupData;
  int length1 = iconGroupData.Length;
  IconClass.NativeMethods.UpdateResource(hUpdate2, type1, name1, (short) num3, data1, length1);
  int num4 = 0;
  int num5 = checked (iconFile.ImageCount - 1);
  int index = num4;
  while (index <= num5)
  {
    byte[] numArray = iconFile.get_ImageData(index);
    IntPtr hUpdate3 = hUpdate1;
    num2 = new IntPtr(3L);
    IntPtr type2 = num2;
    num1 = new IntPtr(checked ((long) iconBaseID + (long) index));
    IntPtr name2 = num1;
    int num6 = 0;
    byte[] data2 = numArray;
    int length2 = numArray.Length;
    IconClass.NativeMethods.UpdateResource(hUpdate3, type2, name2, (short) num6, data2, length2);
    checked { ++index; }
  }
  IconClass.NativeMethods.EndUpdateResource(hUpdate1, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full solution.

First of all you have to thought for a new `file extension` for your application. It could be anything (any combination). Like `.abcd`, `.dea` or anything else. **You cannot go with predefined system extensions like .exe, .dll etc.** So you can think of any extension of **three** or **four** characters long.

You can use following code into your `program.cs`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.IO;

namespace DemoCalc
{

    static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern void SHChangeNotify(uint wEventId, uint uFlags, IntPtr dwItem1, IntPtr dwItem2);
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!IsAssociated())
            {
                Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKeyTree("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FileExts\\.abcd");
                Asociate();
            }
            else
            {
                Asociate();
            }
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Run(new Form1(args[0]));
            }
        }
        public static bool IsAssociated()
        {

            return (Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FileExts\\.abcd", false) == null);

        }
        public static void Asociate()
        {
            String path = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Parent.FullName;
            MessageBox.Show(path);
            path = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(path).FullName + @"\Image\sync.ico";
            MessageBox.Show(path);
            RegistryKey FileReg = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Classes\\.abcd");
            RegistryKey AppReg = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Classes\\Applications\\MyCalcNew.exe");
            RegistryKey AppAssoc = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FileExts\\.abcd");

            FileReg.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon").SetValue("", System.IO.Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetParent(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Parent.FullName).FullName + @"\Image\sync.ico");
            FileReg.CreateSubKey("PerceivedType").SetValue("", "Text");

            AppReg.CreateSubKey("shell\\open\\command").SetValue("", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\" %1");
            AppReg.CreateSubKey("shell\\edit\\command").SetValue("", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\" %1");
            AppReg.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon").SetValue("", System.IO.Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetParent(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Parent.FullName).FullName + @"\Image\sync.ico");

            AppAssoc.CreateSubKey("UserChoice").SetValue("Progid", "Applications\\MyCalcNew.exe");
            SHChangeNotify(0x08000000, 0x0000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using `.abcd` extension for my desktop application. So first of all I am checking whether this extension of mine exist in the `system registry` or not. If it exist then delete it from `Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKeyTree`.

Now you need to associate your new extension or in other words you have to register your new extension in `system registry`.

Check the below line which allows you to map any icon file to your extension.

```
path = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(path).FullName + @"\Image\sync.ico";
```

Here I am using `sync.ico` file. You can use any logo of your company or anything else as the .ico file. Remember this .ico file will stick with your extension. However you can change it later if you wish to.

This will give you two major functionality.

1. When you will save any file with `.abcd extension` then it will
   automatically pick the icon from `system registry` and you will see
   the file with your icon.
2. It will allow you to open your application on mouse `double click`
   or keyboard `enter` event. However to fully achieve this you need to
   write few lines of code at your form level.

Let me know if you are looking for anything else.

Answer (score -1):

You can use of [IconHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to change icons. Note that [shell extensions should not be written in managed code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so you must use unsafe code in your C# codes to write C++ language.